# How to use OR in a CON statement, in the ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm trying to compare two rasters, and create an output based on a formula like:

```
if raster1 > 10 or raster2 < 20 then raster3 = 30
```

How can I specify the OR in the raster calculator's CON statement?

The pages [Building expressions in Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000zn000000) and [Conditional evaluation with CON](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000008000000) don't help, and "or" seems to be keyword that Google ignores....

Comment: please statement with me erosion map with mpeciac method thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For building complex statements, you can get more information [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Building_complex_statements/00p60000000p000000/)

> It is important to know the precedence level of the operators. For
> example, Boolean (~, &, ^,|) operators have a higher precedence level
> than Relational (<, <=, >, >=, ==, !=) operators, which has an impact
> on how you construct your expressions. For more information on
> operator precedence, see the second table on this [page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Working_with_operators_in_Map_Algebra/00p600000008000000/)

I copied the above-mentioned table at the end of my post, it goes from lowest to highest precedence(note that it is not the same [precedence in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)).  Operators with the highest precedence are grouped together first, this is why you need parentheses if you want to force evaluating ">" before "|".

Without parentheses, your parser is trying to read

```
Con(("Raster1" > (10 | "Raster2") < 20),30)
```

> <, <=, >, >=, ==, !=
> (Less Than, Less Than Equal, Greater Than, Greater Than Equal, Equal To, Not Equal)
>
> |
> (Boolean Or)
>
> ^
> (Boolean XOr)
>
> &
> (Boolean And)
>
> <<, >>
> (Bitwise Left Shift, Bitwise Right Shift)
>
> +, -
> (Addition, Subtraction)
>
> *, /, //, %
> (Multiplication, Division, Integer Division, Modulo)
>
> +, -, ~
> (Unary Plus, Negate, Boolean Not)
>
> **
> (Power)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on why the parentheses are required - that makes a lot of sense now

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent ages on this, so to spare everyone else the trouble here's the cheat sheet:

It appears you need to surround each individual comparison in brackets, and use the `|` symbol as the "or":

`Con(("Raster1" > 10) | ("Raster2" < 20),30)`

*(Please edit this answer, and post a link to the documentation which mentions this, if it exists)*

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000 it's in the table. The brackets around the statements aren't just nice they're *absolutely essential* - did my head in on that for a few minutes!

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson yeah it's weird since it works without the brackets if you use a simple expression. Googling "boolean or" finds that page you linked, too.